# cordova add splashscreen images

Tags: cordova, copy, splash-screen

I have a cordova project (not phonegap). I've managed to place the icons in a folder and in my config so that they are copied on the build command. Ho do I do the same with splash screens?

```
<platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/icon/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    ...

<platform name="ios">
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    ...
```

Is there a similare config setting for screen/splash?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ANDROID

In the top-level config.xml file (not the one in platforms), add the following preferences:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
```

The first line sets the image to display as the splash screen. This is the file name of the png in the drawable* directories, minus the .png extension. The default value for SplashScreen is screen (for the file platforms/android/res/drawable*/screen.png), so if you name the image anything other than screen.png in the drawable* directories, you need to add/modify this line.

The second line sets the default delay of how long the splashscreen appears in milliseconds. This should be the worst-case expected start time. The default value for SplashScreenDelay is 3000 ms.

IOS

Copy splash screen images into the iOS project's Resources/splash directory. Only add those images for the devices you want to support, such as iPad or iPhone

Apache Cordova Reference [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens)

Comment: Ok, so it works differentley from icons? Its not copied when running cordova build cli?

Comment: Correct. When running the build with cordova cli the splash assets are not copied. Only when using phonegap build. Here is a link that goes into more detail http://devgirl.org/2013/09/12/phonegap-icons-and-splash-screens-help/

Comment: Managed to solve it. Android didnt work according to instr. above. I needed to add super.setIntegerProperty(“splashscreen”, R.drawable.screen); in onCreate() method to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply splash screens the same way you apply icons starting with Cordova 3.5.0
Just put `<splash>` tag inside your `platform` tag and specify correct dimensions, then splash screen would be copied for the appropriate location.

**Note:** Cordova 3.5.0 supports iPhone 5 only.
Support for the iPhone6 and iPhone 6+ is currently implemented and should be available starting from the Cordova 3.7